# enumerating keys in SharedObject

Tags: apache-flex

in my code i get SharedObject instance:

`_so=SharedObject.getRemote("streamSO",_soConnection.uri,true);`

My question: is it possible to enumerate everything under `_so.data` without prior knowledge 
of property names?

Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
for(var key:String in _so.data)
{
   trace(key+' : '+_so.data[key]);
}
```

I'm not certain if this works with shared objects though, but it's worth a shot.